How to use `?pgbouncer=true` with Prisma Accelerate and Supabase
I am working on a project using supabase postgres and prisma accelerate. and running into this ConnectorError: 42P05 which requires project restart every time it occurs, which is frequent.
> “prepared statement \“s#\” does not exist”


Apparently this is common as mentioned in supabase prisma integration docs: Prepared statements error

To prevent Supavisor from erroring, it is necessary to add the following query parameter to your connection strings: pgbouncer=true to the Transaction connection pooler string.

I tried adding ?pgbouncer=true to the connection string as suggested but prisma accelerate setup throw the error:
One or more fields were invalid: [connectionString]

Did you change max_prepared_statements in pgbouncer to non-zero value?

Is this option available on prisma or supabase? If so, where do I add this cofig?.
